# How to perform diff over encoded content

Tags: python, encoding, gzip, diff

I want to perform DIFF over encoded content (gzip mainly), Is there any way ?
Right now I am decoding the content and performing the diff, it adds a lot of time overhead.

I am using python zlib library for decodig and libdiff for taking diff.

Comment: Do you want to know if there are any differences, or what the differences are? What is the content?

Comment: I want to know the actual differences in such a way that, I can take diff = file1 and file2 and later I should be able to recover file2 = file1 + diff.
I hope it answers your question?

Comment: Not entirely. The key thing is whether the differences in the original content are important - if they are (e.g. you want to show line-by-line diff of zipped code files) then you will have to unzip. Otherwise, you can just deal with the differences in the zipped version.

Comment: I am okay as long as I am able to recover the second encoded file (zipped) by apply diff on the first encoded file(zipped) i.e.  `d= diff(encoded file 1, encoded file2 ) ,,,,encoded file 2 = encoded file 1 + diff`

Comment: Although you could diff the compressed binary it isn't a good idea because from the point of the difference the rest of the file(s) will be different because a change in the uncompressed data has an effect on all following compressed data. So unless the differences are all towards the end of the files you will get bigger diffs than using the actual data (and compressing the diff).

Answer (score 1):

It is pointless to do a diff of a compressed file if there are any differences, since the entire compressed file will be different after the first difference in the uncompressed data.  If there are a small set of differences in the uncompressed data, then the only way to find those is to uncompress the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bsdiff4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bsdiff4/1.1.4). It allows to diff of binary content (or text with very long lines).

Here is an example use. First we build a `10**6` byte array of `a`

```
import bsdiff4
a = bytes(10**6 * 'a')
```

Then, make a copy of the array, and introduce a difference

```
b = bytearray(a)
b[100:106] = ' diff '
```

We ask for the diff:

```
diff = bsdiff4.diff(a, bytes(b))
```

This diff can be used to retrieve `b` from `a`:

```
bsdiff4.patch(a, diff) == b
```

It works with python 2 and python 3.